# Access parameters from a URL in ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am receiving the following URL and the Callback view from the `ProcessToken` controller is being displayed:

> ```
> http://localhost:4151/ProcessToken/CallBack#token_type=Bearer&access_token=54EXXXXXXXXX3GE4
> ```

In `Callback` `ActionResult` code, I want to access the `token_type` and `access_token`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the fragment and therefore you cannot access it at server side.

Read this: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4

```
When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
retrieval action has been successfully completed.  As such, it is not
part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.
```

You can access query-string-parameters with model-binding as ken4z pointed out.

You can read the hash-part with jquery:

```
var data = window.location.hash.substring(1);
$.post('[YOUR_URL]', data, function () {
    // SUCCEEDED, redirect or so
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so the # is an anchor tag.
Can anyone help me with some javascript code to cause a  post to so the controller can deal with it?

I.E. post to

http://localhost:4151/ProcessToken/CallBack?token_type=Bearer&access_token=54EXXXXXXXXX3GE4

It seems that I cant actually access it user querystring ..

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information and an example of what you think the ActionResult method should be.  But based on what I think you are asking:

```
public ActionResult CallBack(string token_type, string access_token){ //Do Something }
```

Answer (score 1):

do what ken4z suggested, if not, you can always read the query strings from the Request object.

```
Request.QueryString["token_type"]
Request.QueryString["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ken4z says, you should use parameters to model bind. Otherwise, you can use Request.QueryString to access them.